# Here Maps API - Basic place display (placeId)

Tags: javascript, api, here-api

I implemented the map on web page using JavaScript API, and now I want to show the basic information about some location. In JavaScript API documentation, I found a part of which is called "Basic place display" in Places Components section, but there is an example of how to render information using placeId.

I need to be able to retrieve information using location coordinates if it is possible. I tried to display information using PHP code that define coordinates for some location on the map instead of using placeId, but it's not working.

This is an example of code that I used:

```
var basicPlace = new nokia.places.widgets.Place({
                    placeId: PHP code instead of placeId. 
                    *exp: [<?php   code;?>, <?php echo code;?>],*
                    targetNode: "map",
                    template: "nokia.blue.place"
            });
```

Is it possible to solve the problem like that, or there is a method that does not involve placeId.

Links: [Here Developer](http://developer.here.com/), [Here JavaScript API](http://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/api-explorer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read  the **nokia.places.widgets.Place** [documentation](http://developer.here.com/docs/maps_js/topics_api_pub/nokia.places.widgets.Place.html), you will see that placeId is a **mandatory** parameter. It is in effect the primary key for the place information that is held by HERE. You will therefore need to make another request using the JavaScript API prior to display in order to obtain the placeId so you can show your place details. The obvious thing to do here is to make a category request first, and store the placeId with each marker as shown below:

```
// Function for receiving search results from places search and process them
var processResults = function (data, requestStatus, requestId) {
    var i, len, locations, marker;

    if (requestStatus == "OK") {
        locations = data.results ? data.results.items : [data.location];
        if (locations.length > 0) {
            for (i = 0, len = locations.length; i < len; i++) {
                // Add a marker and store the placeId
                marker = new nokia.maps.map.StandardMarker(locations[i].position, 
                    { text: i+1 ,
                        placeId : locations[i].placeId});
                resultSet.objects.add(marker);
            }

        } 
});
// etc.. etc...
```

The second part is to add the click listener which displays an infobubble and populates the Place Widget using the stored **placeId**:

```
  resultSet.addListener("click" ,  function(evt) {
                infoBubbles.openBubble("<div id='basicPlaceContainer'></div>",
                                     evt.target.coordinate);

                var basicPlace = new nokia.places.widgets.Place({
                    placeId: evt.target.placeId,
                    targetNode: "basicPlaceContainer",
                    template: "nokia.blue.bubble"
                });

            }, false);
```

The complete working example can be seen below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7; IE=EmulateIE9; IE=10" />
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title>Nokia Maps API for JavaScript Example: Search by category</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Search by category"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="http://js.cit.api.here.com/se/2.5.3/jsl.js?with=all"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mapContainer" style="width:540px; height:334px;"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript" id="exampleJsSource">
/*  Setup authentication app_id and app_code 
*/
nokia.Settings.set("app_id", "YOUR APP ID"); 
nokia.Settings.set("app_code", "YOUR APP CODE");
// Use staging environment (remove the line for production environment)
nokia.Settings.set("serviceMode", "cit");


// Get the DOM node to which we will append the map
var mapContainer = document.getElementById("mapContainer");
// Create a map inside the map container DOM node
var map = new nokia.maps.map.Display(mapContainer, {
    // Initial center and zoom level of the map
    center: [52.51, 13.4],
    zoomLevel: 10,
    components: [       
        new nokia.maps.map.component.Behavior()
    ]
});
this.infoBubbles = new nokia.maps.map.component.InfoBubbles();
map.components.add(infoBubbles);

var searchCenter = new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(52.51, 13.4),
    searchManager = nokia.places.search.manager,
    resultSet;

// Function for receiving search results from places search and process them
var processResults = function (data, requestStatus, requestId) {
    var i, len, locations, marker;

    if (requestStatus == "OK") {
        locations = data.results ? data.results.items : [data.location];
        if (locations.length > 0) {
            if (resultSet) map.objects.remove(resultSet);
            resultSet = new nokia.maps.map.Container();
            resultSet.addListener("click" ,  function(evt) {
                infoBubbles.openBubble("<div id='basicPlaceContainer'></div>", evt.target.coordinate);

                var basicPlace = new nokia.places.widgets.Place({
                    placeId: evt.target.placeId,
                    targetNode: "basicPlaceContainer",
                    template: "nokia.blue.bubble"
                });

            }, false);


            for (i = 0, len = locations.length; i < len; i++) {
                marker = new nokia.maps.map.StandardMarker(locations[i].position, 
                    { text: i+1 ,
                        placeId : locations[i].placeId});
                resultSet.objects.add(marker);
            }
            map.objects.add(resultSet);
            map.zoomTo(resultSet.getBoundingBox(), false);
        } else { 
            alert("Your search produced no results!");
        }
    } else {
        alert("The search request failed");
    }
};



// Make a place search request
var category = "eat-drink";

map.addListener("displayready", function () {
    searchManager.findPlacesByCategory({
        category: category,
        onComplete: processResults,
        searchCenter: searchCenter
    });
});

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The result can be see below:

[image: Restaurants in Berlin.]

Comment: This helped me a lot to understand things, thank you. One more question. If I want to show info about just one place on the map that is defined by coordinates obtained from php code can I use this example above? My map [example](http://i.imgur.com/jQHXxeT.png)

Comment: If you are attempting to access HERE Places server side, then you'll need to use the [RESTful Places API](http://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/places). I would make a request for a single place using the `size=1` parameter like the following to obtain a single place Id: [45.81,15.97 = Zagrebačko Kazalište Mladih](http://demo.places.nlp.nokia.com/places/v1/discover/here?at=45.8112199%2C15.9761811&size=1&result_types=place&app_code=gBoUkAMoxoqIWfxWA5DuMQ&app_id=_peU-uCkp-j8ovkzFGNU)

Comment: Thanks for the RESTful tip. I have modified your example above, now I just need to ut marker on the map.center position and add info bubble with place info. Place = map.center. Can that be done with Here JS API? My exp: http://pastebin.com/8Qfsey1U

Comment: This [example](http://developer.here.com/apiexplorer/examples/api-for-js/information-bubbles/marker-with-information-bubble.html) shows how to place a marker at the center of the screen and open it on click. Combining it with the code above you'll need to use the _on-click-open-basic-place-widget_ code instead. Similarly when you create the standard marker you'll need `marker = new nokia.maps.map.StandardMarker[<?php echo $data['lat'];?>, <?php echo $data['lon'];?>], {placeId : <?php echo $data['placeId'];?>});`  where `placeId` has been retrieved from your RESTful call in the php code.